# How can I move x axis of highchart in a particular time period?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I would like to move x axis of my highchart according to time period, i.e. if i am showing data of 5 minutes with a tick interval of 1 minute so on 6th minute the x axis is shifted by one minute e.g. At the initialization of chart if I am showing data 12:01 PM to 12:06 PM then at 12:07PM it should show data from 12:02 PM to 12:07 PM.

Comment: Hi @Aayush Chaudhary, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qca6k3td/

Comment: I can't because it's a codebase of company but thanks I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this problem by updating min and max of x-axis i.e. I took a variable of  5 minute in milliseconds. I took a variable `startingTime = this.chart.xAxis[0].min` which take minimum time on the x-axis when high chart initialised then I checked if the current time minus `startingTime` is greater then the `interval` variable then update the x-axis min

```
if((Date.now() - startingTime) > interval){
          this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
                  min: Date.now() - interval,
                  max: Date.now()
           });
         startingTime = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
  }
```